# How to place scroll bar on all sides of div.(horizontal(top,bottom), vertical(left,right)

Tags: html, materialize

How to place scroll bar on all sides of div.(horizontal(top,bottom), vertical(left,right)
I'm able to get the scrollbar for horizonal-bottom and vertical-right.
Materialise Css is used.

```
<body>
<div style="border:2px solid black;height: 100px; direction: rtl; overflow: auto; width: 150px;">
<div style="direction: ltr; height: 100px ;overflow:auto;">
data
</div>
</div>
</body>
```